# show only item related to a user - help with view / list (updated)

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, custom-form

Sorry, did not know how to formulate the title, might sound a bit strange.
I created a Form + Workflow which goes through some approval stages:

- Pending > when is raised and needs approval
- Approved > when it has been approved by the Manager at least
- Rejected > well there not much to say to it lol

I also created a view `UserView` to show all the existing tickets to the user [Me] however, I was thinking to create a view which shows:

> the tickets only relevant to the Manager | Exec. | Finance

For reference, when raising a Form the cost centre number is entered (there are over 30 cost centers available) and my thoughts were to make the view = show only by CostCentre Nr. but how to make it show only to the next person who needs to approve it ?!

**UPDATE**

[image]

To give a better understanding, I have attached some screenshots; below you see folders Pending | Approved | Rejected and My Requests. Each of the folders is linked to the specific `View`

Though, them three folders is visible only to the FINANCE Team. Meaning, they can see all tickets from every cost centre whether it is pending rejected or approved.

The `My Requests` is again a ViewStyle restricted to show [ME] only your own tickets. Which is aimed for the users only who have raised a request.

[image]

**What is the issue here?**

With my current approach, the Managers and the Exec's cannot see any of the forms that has been raised or that needs to be approved.

**What I want to achieve?**

Ideally, I like so that each Manager and Execs *can see only the forms* (ticket whatever you may be referring to) that they have been assigned to for approval or simply where they are responsible to.

Maybe a way of saying "show items only based on the login" ?!

**Example:**

Manager: Max  -   Exec:  Gary

**Max** > needs 5 Forms approving | has approved 3 forms already | 2 rejected
**Gary** > 3 forms to approve (pending) | has 1 approved and 1 rejected

Current situation: whether a Manager or an Exec's they could see ALL the raised forms across all the department and that is not really ideal.

Question is:

> to restrict the View so each Manager | Exec can only see what is
>   assigned to them

Comment: Please edit your question and put some sample data with screenshot so that someone can understand....

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia yep done that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new view, and you have Filter option on view settings. By which you can apply the filter on assigned to column or any column that holds the name of the current user on an item. You can make this view public and also have it as a default view for that list from the view settings.

Comment: meaning I got to create a separate view for each Manager and Exec > over 50 member of staff. Is there no other options around it?

Comment: just to clarify - when the form has been raised, the FlexiTasks sends an email to a group (containing of 4 emails) and once it has been approved their name will be updated in the "approved by..." field. Until then , it will remain blank and therefore to say "make the filter show username by the approval field" does not work ... not sure if that is clear enough.

Comment: Unless the person's name/ details are captured under a column for an item, how can you filter the item by the user ? So I mean to say have a column like assigned to/ pending with and make the workflow to update this column at each level of the workflow with the appropriate manager/exec. So when the user opens the list view, you can show the items that are assigned to/related to them.

Comment: exactly, there is no field stating "to be approved by..." and if that is the case then need to add extra field for every approver. Hmmm will think about this option. cheers

Comment: no, not for every approver. Here the field is for the item, so now every item needs ' to be approved by' data. So you create a site column(field) of type people picker and name it as  'to be approved by'. Now using the workflow, set the value for this column. Conclusion be like every item has a to be assigned by column which will capture one/more than one approver/exec guy's name. This name you have to set it using the WF. Cheers

Comment: ahhhh!! right! Create one field and make the WF update it after each level who the next approver is :) good point. Think got it this time

Comment: :) Great ! If that solves your problem, mark my response as answer :)

Comment: I give it a try and see how things work out :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, ideally you should be using Item level permission and assign permission to each item from workflow based on user Managers/Execs, Also you need to create multiple views like My View, Manager's View, Execs View. This way they will be able to view items related to them on which they have access. Item creator will already have access to item which he created. Your workflow will do the trick to assign permission to item for Manager and Execs.

Update

1. Break inheritance of List, Enable Item level permission.
2. Create a workflow, which triggers on Item creation.
3. In this workflow Assign permission to particular list item based on Requests Manager, Execs, Assuming for each user, there would be master list which tell who is manager, who is execs or may be group.
4. Above will make sure that each list item in List can be accessed only by 3 persons 1. Requester himself, His Manager, His EXECs.
5. Now you would need different Views for each type of User, Manager and Exec. Follow normal steps to create views.
6. As we have item level permission enabled, Manager will only be able to see requests(list items) on which he has access. Same would be case with EXECs.

You can refer below link to on

[Assign item level permission through workflow](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/)

Note - Enabling item level degrade performance based on how many items you are going to create in this list. so please consider this also before going by this approach.

Comment: you lost me on this one ... struggling to understand what you mean :(

Comment: do you mean this: https://s22.postimg.org/slaqf3dch/Flexi_Task_assigning_Permission.jpg  > set user permission ?

Comment: would appreciate if you could add some samples screenshot :) to make it a bit clear to me, thanks.

Comment: @Bucki...modified answer in detail, hope this make sense... :)

Comment: I think I kind of understood your suggestion. Right, what I have done so far is > I stopped the parental inheritage for Approval | Rejected | Pending folders and is accessible by Exec | Managers and Finance . The next step > FlexiTask in WF I set the user permission to Approve and once completed to Read (example view: https://s22.postimg.org/slaqf3dch/Flexi_Task_assigning_Permission.jpg) is that what you mean ???

Comment: yes...you are getting there :)

Comment: hmmm I am stuck with the view settings! What am I basing the filters on? Show the items when column: Manager `is equal to` empty - [Me]?